# Panel Popup In JSF 1.1

Tags: java, jsf, panel

Is it possible to have panel popup window in JSF 1.1 ? I would like to display a popup window when I click edit button and then would like to have few components in that panel popup window.

I am not using any other JSF like icefaces or richfaces, just plain JSF 1.1.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Just bring in some good shot of JavaScript and/or CSS to show/hide and style the popup window. That's also what the average component library like RichFaces is doing with the only difference that it's all wrapped in a simple JSF component.

At its simplest you can use JS `window.open()` on click of a button/link.

```xml
<h:commandButton value="Edit" onclick="window.open('edit.jsf?id=#{item.id}'); return false;" />
```

The `window.open()` allows for fine grained customization of the window, such as the size and the browser bars which are to be displayed/hidden. Read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) to learn about them. Returning `false` is mandatory to prevent the button from unnecessarily submitting the form.

Then, in the constructor of the backing bean associated with `edit.jsf`, you can grab the item by the `id` which is been passed as request parameter.

```
private Item item;

public EditItemBean() {
    String id = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    this.item = someItemService.find(Long.valueOf(id));
}
```

Nasty, but that's what you get with JSF 1.1 which doesn't offer a JSF 1.2-supported `@PostConstruct` annotation or JSF 2.0-supported `<f:viewParam>` tag.

Finally, in the `edit.jsf` you need to bring in some conditionally rendered JavaScript piece which reloads the parent window (so that the edited data is redisplayed) and closes the popup window.

```xml
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{editItem.save}" />
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{editItem.success}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Set the `success` boolean in the action method when the saving is successful.

```
public void save() {
    // ...

    this.success = true;
}
```

There exist also solutions using a so-called "overlay window" dialog which is basically `<div>` which is positioned using CSS `position: fixed;` and spans the entire browser window with a transparent background and then therein another `<div>` which is centered and contains the real form. This however requires a bigger shot of JS/CSS. This is also what the average JSF component library and JavaScript framework/plugin (such as jQuery or YUI) is basically doing. It's only trickier to get it work seamlessly together with JSF as you would of course like to redisplay the popup when a validation error on the popup form occurs and that kind of things. It's much easier if you're using an ajax-enabled JSF implementation/library.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. Could it be possible to do something like this `<ice:panelPopup modal="true" visible="#{myBean.editPopupVisible}">
  <ice:form>
    <ice:input...> some inputs...
    ... Save/Cancel button
  </ice:form>
</ice:panelPopup>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't do IceFaces. Also, IceFaces is not "plain JSF 1.1".

Comment: when Icefaces is mentioned, I do have a question, which one you'd prefer for JSF, icefaces or richfaces or apache faces or something else?, in terms od reliability and less number of bugs

Comment: -@BalusC whatever inside `<h:panelGroup` will be displayed based on rendered property, but javascript executes regardless I guess. For testing I added the following `<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
 <h3> Result </h3> 
 <h:outputLabel value="ppo"></h:outputLabel>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       //window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();     
    </script>
 </h:panelGroup>` javascript  is getting executed, however outputtext is not displayed.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's just your misintepretation of what happens on the client side.

Comment: -@BalusC so how this would work `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{editItem.success}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>` Sorry about my ignorance

Comment: I managed to get this working ,except for one small hiccup. After doing all the processing in popup i.e. edit.jsp, like you mentioned I am setting the boolean value `success  = true`. Issue I am facing now is next time when popup is clicked again `editItem.success` is `true`. I tried setting in actionListener and action method's but of no use. While calling edit.jsp, I am passing return false in window.open. How could I make `success = false` when user opens popup window?

Comment: The bean is supposed to be request scoped.

Comment: When I change the scope to request, then it is working. However  the values doesn't appear in JSF page after the refresh if it session is request. I have the following to refresh the page. `opener.focus(); 
opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
self.close(); ` Values are getting assigned to setters correctly in bean though.

Comment: Upon getting values in bean from JSP page, I am setting the values like the following `bean.setEmpNo(bean.getHiddenInput());` I could see from log that values are being set, however nothing is displayed in JSF page.